# Stripping special characters in the string

Tags: java

How to strip all the special characters in a given string. I tried by using charAt(i) to check for every character. But its dirty. Is there any better way to acheive the same?

Comment: What characters are "special characters" in your definition? Why do you think your solution is "dirty"?

Comment: I have mentioned that i have used charAt(i) function to check for each and every character and to replace them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.replaceAll(regexp, replaceChar)
```

and check the String / Regexp documentation for escaping characters and the rest of mighty Regexp-fu!